# Notation for corresponding variables

Tags: notation

I am not sure how to express this in correct math notation. I have a vector $a$ of values  $a_i$. For every $a_i$ there exists a correspondig set of variables $b_i$ and $c_i$. $b_i$ and $c_i$ have different values for every $a_i$. Basically it is like an excell sheet with three colums a, b, c. How do I express this?

Comment: Well, you can add indices to $c$ and $b$ too: $c_i, b_i$. What more do you require?

Comment: I came across this set notation {...}. I just would like to express this more clearly with an proper notation. Maybe I am searching for a this var CORRESPONDS to this var.